# How do I move a ball up and down depending on a tap using Spritekit and Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

My code for my `touchesBegan` method is this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let moveBall = SKAction.moveToY(380, duration: 0.4)
    let moveBalldown = SKAction.moveToY(293, duration: 0.4)
    if ball.position.y == 293 {
        ball.runAction(moveBall)
    }
    if ball.position.y == 380 {
        ball.runAction(moveBalldown)
    }
```

When I tap the screen, nothing happens.

I want the ball to move up and down depending on the tap.

The ball should move up on the first tap and then back down once it is at `y = 380`, and the screen is tapped again.

Here is the rest of the code that affects the ball.

```
var ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball")

self.ball.position = CGPoint(x:40, y:293)
self.addChild(self.ball)
self.ball.yScale = 0.17
self.ball.xScale = 0.17

self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.height * 0.08)
ball.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

var degreeRotation = CDouble(self.SBEBSpeed) * M_PI / 180
self.ball.zRotation -= CGFloat(degreeRotation)

let moveBall = SKAction.moveToY(380, duration: 0.4)
let moveBalldown = SKAction.moveToY(293, duration: 0.4)
if ball.position.y == 293 {
    ball.runAction(moveBall)
}
if ball.position.y == 380 {
    ball.runAction(moveBalldown)
}
```

Comment: You should initialize your ball in the view did load method and not in touchesBegan , I mean self.addChild should be in view did load

Comment: My self.addChild is in my viewdidload

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things, though. Make sure you add the ball in the didMoveToView function. To keep things clean I've made a function for that `addBall()`.

They way you want to move the ball you don't need the physics so I left that out of this solution.

I've made the `touchesBegan` function have only one if-statement for both possibilities.

I hope this works for you! I've tried this and it works for me.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        // Make sure you have this function here
        addBall()
    }

    func addBall() {

        self.ball.position = CGPoint(x: 40, y: 293)
        self.ball.yScale = 0.17
        self.ball.xScale = 0.17

        self.addChild(self.ball)

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        let moveBall = SKAction.moveToY(380, duration: 0.4)
        let moveBalldown = SKAction.moveToY(293, duration: 0.4)

        // If the position of the ball is not 293 it will move to 293, otherwise it will move to 380
        if ball.position.y == 293 {
            self.ball.runAction(moveBall)
        } else {
            self.ball.runAction(moveBalldown)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: None of this seems to be the problem. The only other difference in our two sets of code is in the touchesBegan func, you have "touches: Set<NSObject>" and I have "touches: NSSet". Would this have something to do with the issue? Also, when I try to use that, I get an error saying "use of undeclared type 'Set'".